# How to upgrade Mono 2.4 to mono 2.6.4 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-11.04

I have installed ubuntu 11.04 and based on the Mono website Ubuntu 11.04 should come with Mono 2.6.4 (http://www.mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu). but when I installed MonoDevelop I got the version 2.4. Now I want to have Mono 2.6.4 . Does anyone know how should I upgrade it on Ubuntu 11.04?

Cheers;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mono 2.6, but mono **develop** 2.4.  If you really need monodevelop 2.6 you can install it from source, but this can go horribly wrong.  A script like this will probably help:

http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/05/install-mono-2-10-2-and-monodevelop-2-6-beta-3-on-ubuntu-or-fedora-with-a-bash-script/

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem is that I am using csharp and at the moment when I open the project I don't have LINQ. Therefore I don't have using System.Linq;. Is updating monodevelop helps solving that problem?

Comment: I think you just need to update the target framework for your project to 3.5

Comment: Thanks for this. but I have gone to Project=>solution option=> version and have changed the version to 3.5 from 1.0 but it is still having the same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if monodevelop automatically adds the reference to System.Core.dll when you change target version.  You may need to add it yourself.

Comment: It is working now.First I went to the Solution option and changed the version to 3.5 and then I went to project=>Edit references and added the System.Core.dll. Thanks a lot for your help.